# Como encontrar um padrão para manter a mesma modelagem de dados entre um objeto JSON, um POJO e JPA?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, pojo

Para facilitar o entendimento da minha pergunta, segue o seguinte exemplo:

Um POJO:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String location;

}
```

String JSON:

```
String json = {name:"Jose", location:"Eslovenia"};
```

Serialização:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Person p = gson.fromJson(json, Person.class);
```

Insert na base dados:

```
 Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
 session.beginTransaction();

 session.save(p);
 ...
```

Noto que em diversos exemplos sempre existe um padrão de campos tanto de um objeto json para um objeto java e um objeto java para os campos do banco de dados.

A dúvida não é a nível de código e sim conceitual:

**1** - Nos exemplos com alguns campos funciona de forma ok, mas em um sistema real, é possível manter tal padrão nos 3 níveis (json, java e banco) com muito mais campos e complexidade?

**2** - Se for possível manter, trabalhar dessa forma é considerado uma boa prática de programação seguir esse tipo de padrão?

**3** - Existe algum caso que esse padrão seria impraticável?

**4** - A modelagem do Banco de Dados deve refletir no POJO e o POJO deve servir de base para o objeto json?

Qualquer outra consideração fora as perguntas também é muito bem vinda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imaginando que este JSON vai ser usado em uma API:

> 1 - Nos exemplos com alguns campos funciona de forma ok, mas em um
>   sistema real, é possível manter tal padrão nos 3 níveis (json, java e
>   banco) com muito mais campos e complexidade?

Possível tudo é :). Em projetos pequenos, acredito que você até consegue manter esta estrutura e que funcionará muito bem para um pequeno sistema monolítico, sendo bastante produtivo com ele. Mas logo perceberá que isto não funcionará com o tempo.

> 2 - Se for possível manter, trabalhar dessa forma é considerado uma
>   boa prática de programação seguir esse tipo de padrão?

Eu não vejo problemas se isto estiver facilitando sua vida. Como disse anteriormente, para casos simples funcionará e trará um grande ganho de tempo. Mas se este sistema tende a crescer muito e ganhar complexidade, este modelo terá data de validade.

No primeiro caso que você não quiser/puder obedecer este comportamento, você começará a sair deste padrão, e ele parará de fazer sentido e trazer dores de cabeça.

> 3 - Existe algum caso que esse padrão seria impraticável?

Citando alguns exemplos:

- Imagine que você tenha um POJO Pessoa (creio que no seu caso, o POJO é uma entidade JPA/Hibernate, mas vamos chamar de POJO) com 15 campos (nome, data de nascimento, sexo, idade, estado civil, etc). Dentre eles, 5 são obrigatórios. Faz sentido os 15 estarem sempre no seu request/response? Se tiver campos com 100 ou até 1000 caracteres, você precisará sempre retornar eles? E se tiver informações sensíveis da Pessoa (chave primária, documento, etc), precisará controlar com anotações do Gson no POJO para não enviá-las (pode ter casos que você gostaria e outras não). E a lista segue...
- Se você precisar mudar seu POJO (separar uma tabela em duas outras tabelas, mover campos para outro POJO, mudar o nome de um campo, etc), seu JSON vai mudar também... qual o impacto desta mudança na sua aplicação que envia/consome o JSON a cada vez que isto ocorrer?
- Se precisar disponibilizar um micro-serviço que salva Pessoa para outros sistemas, é provável que os atributos de `Pessoa` não seja o ideal para o entendimento deste serviço para outros sistemas que se comunicarão com ele.

> 4 - A modelagem do Banco de Dados deve refletir no POJO e o POJO deve
>   servir de base para o objeto json?

O modelo que é simples e funciona bem, ao meu ver, é:

- O serviço que disponibilizará este JSON é representado por um DTO, que será serializado/deserializado. Ele será usado apenas para ser preenchido com as informações **necessárias**.
- O DTO não consegue acessar o POJO, ficaria em um projeto diferente. Motivo? Se você amarrar seu POJO ao DTO você fica refém das mudanças do POJO, mesmo que em um grau muito menor que o proposto na sua pergunta. Ao meu ver, as mudanças do POJO nunca devem refletir diretamente no seu DTO.

Como sugestão de organização e sem deixar muito complexo, penso em uma organização com três projetos:

- **projeto-api** (depende do projeto-service):

  - Contém: DTOs.
  - Responsabilidade: preenche e serializa/deserializa o DTO com as informações recebidas pelo `service`. Pode usar VOs para esta comunicação com o projeto-service.
- **projeto-service** (depende do projeto-dominio):

  - Contém: services (para as regras de negócio) e VOs.
  - Responsabilidade: Ele invoca os métodos de busca/salvar/atualizar/remover do projeto-dominio passando o POJO e utilizando VOs para se comunicar com o projeto-api.
- **projeto-dominio**:

  - Contém: POJOs.
  - Responsabilidade: salvar no banco de dados o POJO, contendo os métodos de busca/salvar/atualizar/remover.

Dá para melhorar, isto é apenas um exemplo.

Sobre esta nomenclatura de VO, POJO, DTO, etc, não se preocupe, [isto não é bem definido mesmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans). Apenas crie um padrão para o seu projeto ao utilizar cada nomenclatura.

Comment: primeiramente obrigado pelas respostas bem detalhadas. Achei a ideia bem próxima do que o Fabio comentou anteriormente, praticamente um consenso, o que é bom.

O que eu entendi foi que para não ter uma modelagem tão engessada e trabalhar com uma possível modularidade, então um DTO receberia os dados, um POJO seria utilizado para persistência e um VO para retornar os dados? 

Na resposta anterior, foi sugerido utilizar o Dozer para fazer uma atribuição de dados automática com pequenas customizações entre POJO e o DTO. Nesse sentido, você tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

Não vejo problemas em manter esse padrão em casos mais simples como o CRUD, porém, em modelos mais complexos tenho utilizado um objeto que representa a consulta na base e outro para transferir dados para a view, desta forma consigo criar uma query que tenha a melhor performance possível e utilizo um DTO para representar o JSON necessário para comunicação com a view.

A modelagem da base não deveria restringir o que você deve fazer no código, tendo em vista que em geral utilizamos bases relacionais e trabalhamos com linguagens orientadas a objeto, deixaríamos de aproveitar algumas funcionalidades como herança se o fizessemos.

Na prática tenho utilizado o Dozer para executar a transformação do POJO ou VO para o DTO, que transfere dados de uma classe para outra por convenção (campos com mesmo nome) ou configuração descrita em um XML.